# Create an object by reflection

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to create an object using reflection like this
(maybe this is not a good architecture but I'm just doing some tests)

```
package com.interfaces;

public interface IEmployee {
   List<entities.Employee> getEmployees(); 
}
```

then

```
package com.personnel;

public class Employee implements IEmployee{
  public Employee(){}

  public List<entities.Employee> getEmployees(){
     ...
  }
}
```

then in another class

```
package com.factory;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public final class EmployeeFactory {

    private static String path = "com.personnel";

    public EmployeeFactory() {}

    public static interfaces.IEmployee CreateEmployee(){
        String className = path + ".Employee";
        try {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
            Object object = cls.newInstance();
            return (interfaces.IEmployee)object;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

then in another class

```
public final class PersonnelService {

    private static interfaces.IEmployee employeeFactory = com.factory.EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee();

    public List<entities.Employee> getEmployees(){
        return employeeFactory.getEmployees();
    }

}
```

finally in my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<entities.Employee> employees = new com.services.PersonnelService().getEmployees();
    for(entities.Employee employee : employees){
        System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeName());
    }
```

when the code arrives to Class cls = Class.forName(className) it throws the exception message "com.personnel.Employee.(java.lang.String)" with "NoSuchMethodException".

---

**UPDATE**

I found the problem. In fact, it was a bad naming convention. I had a serializable Employee class (my pojo) and an Employee class which implements my interface IEmployee which is intended to perform DB operations. I renamed this last one as EmployeeDAL and it worked. Even I defined the full class name as you can see in the example, it looks like that I was trying to instantiate my serializable pojo (I still don't get it, but...). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Based on the error message it would seem somehow .(java.lang.String) is getting added to className but I can't see how. Is this all your relevant code?

Comment: Yes, it is. Basically className variable holds the String which is returned by the exception: «com.personnel.Employee». The three periods is db connect to get my employees but I can't eve get there.

Comment: There's something missing here. `NoSuchMethodException` is a checked exception but you haven't shown any method that can possibly throw it.

Comment: When I instantiate my service PersonnelService it should call immediately the static method CreateEmployee which gives the error. There's no more code than that. Only the three periods which it's a db connection to perform a select (not relevant to the issue).

Comment: What about the `Employee` constructor? Is it really just `public Employee(){}`?

Comment: Yes. The only constructor in the class with no args and with no code inside.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your code and not found any error on this code. I only get NoSuchMethodException message when I change Employee constructor with String argument

```
package com.agit.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> employees = new PersonnelService().getEmployees();
        for(Employee employee : employees){
            System.out.println(employee);
        }
    }
}

interface IEmployee {
    List<Employee> getEmployees(); 
}

class Employee implements IEmployee{
    public Employee(){}

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        List<Employee> x = new ArrayList<>();
        x.add(this);
        return x;
    }
}

final class EmployeeFactory {

    private static String path = "com.agit.example.test";

    public EmployeeFactory() {}

    public static IEmployee CreateEmployee(){
        String className = path + ".Employee";
        try {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
            Object object = cls.newInstance();
            return (IEmployee)object;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

}

final class PersonnelService {

    private static IEmployee employeeFactory = EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee();

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        return employeeFactory.getEmployees();
    }

}
```